# Getting a complete list of contacts from Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get a complete list of contacts from the Microsoft Graph, but no matter which API I use, I only get a handful of contats.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people  seemingly returns the latest contacts I have been dealing with, not even people in my actual contact list.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts  returns like 10 random people from my contact list.

What I would like to accomplish is to get ALL contacts for a user, similar to how the "My People" app works in Windows 10. How, if at all, would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts returns like 10 random people from my contact list.

Like most of the Graph endpoints you need to page the data to get every item from the Contacts folder, 10 items is just the default return value but you could something like

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$Top=1000
```

To get the first 1000 and then page from there. This endpoint will just give you the contacts in the users default Contacts Folder.

Comment: However... I do not seem to be getting _all_ contacts. Checking the list I get in my app to the list in the People app in Windows 10 proves this. Very annoying :(

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts returns contacts only from the default folder. Use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contactFolders to get user's folders and then use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contactFolders/{id}/contacts to get all of contacts